# Use shinyjs to trigger an event based on the current active bsplus carousel slide

Tags: javascript, css, shiny, carousel, shinyjs

I'm trying to trigger an event in my shiny application, based on the slide that is active in a bsplus carousel that's housed within a modalDialog, i feel that using shinyjs is the way forward, given that the class changes to "active" on the data-target in the console, but my js isn't good enough to get started.

The event i wish to trigger is displaying an absolute panel that has been hidden on initialization.

min example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(bsplus)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  hidden(
    absolutePanel(
      id = "button1", top = "20%", right = "20%", fixed = TRUE, 
      actionButton(inputId = "bttn_addmarker", label = "button")
                  )
  )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  showModal(
    modalDialog(
      bs_carousel(id = "examples_carousel",  use_indicators = TRUE) %>%
        bs_set_data(interval = FALSE) %>%
        bs_append("slide where absolute panel should be hidden") %>%
        bs_append("slide where absolute panel should revealed")
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Console view - when data-slide-to="0", i want the absolute panel to be hidden

[image: data-slide-to="0"]

when data-slide-to="1", i want the absolute panel to be shown

[image: data-slide-to="1"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you can use the active value of the data-slide-to attribute to show the button but it does take a fair bit of logic in javascript to do so. We can start with how to unhide that button. When I inspect the hidden button it has class "shinyjs-hide", which has the following css rules:

```css
.shinyjs-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

So simply removing the class when the second li is active will show the button, then adding it back when the second li is not active will hide it again. Doing this is fairly straight forward. We can create a function that checks if the li tag that has a `data-slide-to` attribute equal to 1 has class active. If it's active, change the class of the hidden button to "shinyjs-show", which unhides the button. If it's not then change the class to "shinyjs-hide", which will hide the button.

```js
function checkStatus(){

setTimeout(function(){

if($( `li[data-slide-to='1']` ).attr('class')=='active'){
    
    $('.shinyjs-hide').removeClass().addClass('shinyjs-show');

} else {

    $('.shinyjs-show').removeClass().addClass('shinyjs-hide');    

}

}, 60);



}
```

Now this function needs to be checked each time either of the left or right arrows are clicked. These have class "carousel-control". We can use jQuery to add the `onclick` attribute, which will be set to "checkStatus();" i.e. run the `checkStatus()` function each time the buttons are clicked.

```js
$('.carousel-control').attr('onclick', 'checkStatus();');
```

This needs to be run after the page loads, which can be done using `shinyjs::runjs()` inside the server like this:

```r
  session$onFlushed(function() {
    shinyjs::runjs("$('.carousel-control').attr('onclick', 'checkStatus();');
")
  }, once=TRUE)
```

The `checkStatus()` function has a `setTimeout()` to make the function wait 60ms before running the check, that's because the check needs to be on the slide that has been switched to.

Putting it all together in a shiny app like this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(bsplus)

js <- HTML("

function checkStatus(){

setTimeout(function(){

if($( `li[data-slide-to='1']` ).attr('class')=='active'){
    
    $('.shinyjs-hide').removeClass().addClass('shinyjs-show');

} else {

    $('.shinyjs-show').removeClass().addClass('shinyjs-hide');    

}

}, 60);

}


")


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$script(js)), 
  hidden(
    absolutePanel(
      id = "button1", top = "20%", right = "20%", fixed = TRUE, 
      actionButton(inputId = "bttn_addmarker", label = "button")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  showModal(
    modalDialog(
      bs_carousel(id = "examples_carousel",  use_indicators = TRUE) %>%
        bs_set_data(interval = FALSE) %>%
        bs_append("slide where absolute panel should be hidden") %>%
        bs_append("slide where absolute panel should revealed")
    )
  )
  
  session$onFlushed(function() {
    shinyjs::runjs("$('.carousel-control').attr('onclick', 'checkStatus();');
")
  }, once=TRUE)
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

gives:

[image]